# f:selectItem inside of a composite component

Tags: jsf, checkbox, jsf-2, composite-component

I'm trying to create my own selectManyCheckbox with composite components. But when I try to use my own selectItem component, the items won't be rendered.

selectItem.xhtml:

```
<cc:implementation>

    <f:selectItem rendered="true" id="#{cc.attrs.id}"
        itemDescription="#{cc.attrs.itemDescription}"
        itemDisabled="#{cc.attrs.itemDisabled}"
        itemLabel="#{cc.attrs.itemLabel}" itemValue="#{cc.attrs.itemValue}"
        value="#{cc.attrs.value}">

    </f:selectItem>

</cc:implementation>
```

selectManyCheckbox.xhtml:

```
 <!--Some other stuff like label -->
 <h:selectManyCheckbox styleClass="#{cc.attrs.styleClass}"
                id="#{cc.attrs.id}_checkbox" value="#{cc.attrs.value}"
                layout="pageDirection">

                <cc:insertChildren />
</h:selectManyCheckbox>
```

When I use

```
 <mycomps:selectManyCheckbox id="abc" labelString="Example">
                <mycomps:selectItem itemValue="1" itemLabel="One" />
            </mycomps:selectManyCheckbox>
```

It doesn't work. But when I use

```
<mycomps:selectManyCheckbox id="abc" labelString="Example">
                <f:selectItem itemValue="1" itemLabel="One" />
            </mycomps:selectManyCheckbox>
```

It does! Anybody an idea how i can solve this problem?

thanks!

Comment: I fail to see the point of wrapping `<f:selectItem>` 1:1 in a composite component like that. What exactly is been enhanced here?

Comment: i just left out the other code

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding a `componentType="javax.faces.SelectItrm"` attribute/value to the `cc:interface element. Try like this:

```
<cc:interface componentType="javax.faces.SelectItem">
...
</cc:interface>
<cc:implementation>

    <f:selectItem rendered="true" id="#{cc.attrs.id}"
        itemDescription="#{cc.attrs.itemDescription}"
        itemDisabled="#{cc.attrs.itemDisabled}"
        itemLabel="#{cc.attrs.itemLabel}" itemValue="#{cc.attrs.itemValue}"
        value="#{cc.attrs.value}">

    </f:selectItem>

</cc:implementation>
```

Comment: What is the advantage of having such an 1:1 component?